# How to remove XML elements based on attribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I am struggling with some basic XSLT. I would like to remove an element from some XML depending on whether it has not got a certain attribute(In this case PriorValue).

The XML Looks like this 
The XML is not limited to only the below sections, it has a lot of other sections and the same logic is applied to them as well.

```
   <Emp>
       <Personal>
            <First_Name>abc</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>xyz</Last_Name>
            <Gender>1</Gender>
            <Birth_Date PriorValue="1980-08-05">1980-09-05</Birth_Date>
            <Country_of_Birth PriorValue="600">724</Country_of_Birth>
            <Marital_Status PriorValue="0">1</Marital_Status>
        </Personal>
        <Info>
            <Name>abc</Name>
            <ID>Part time</ID>
            <NoOfProbationDays>0</NoOfProbationDays>
            <EMPtype>0</EMPtype>
            <CountryOfBirth PriorValue="IND">ESP</CountryOfBirth>
        </Info>
    </Emp>
```

The desired XML output looks like this.

```
    <Emp>
        <Personal>
            <Birth_Date PriorValue="1980-08-05">1980-09-05</Birth_Date>
            <Country_of_Birth PriorValue="600">724</Country_of_Birth>
            <Marital_Status PriorValue="0">1</Marital_Status>
        </Personal>
        <Info>
            <CountryOfBirth PriorValue="IND">ESP</CountryOfBirth>
        </Info>
    </Emp>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
<xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(@PriorValue)]"/>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, Also how do i exclude few sections from it. example: suppose there is a summary section and i don't want apply the priorvalue check to it and always want it in the output XML? thanks for your help

Comment: Change `<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(@PriorValue)]"/>` to `<xsl:template match="*[not(self::summary) and not(*) and not(@PriorValue)]"/>`. That should do if your input can have `summary` elements without a `PriorValue` attribute and you want to copy it nevertheless to the result. If `summary` can be a parent of other elements for which you do not want to remove them then use e.g. `<xsl:template match="*[not(self::summary)]/*[not(*) and not(@PriorValue)]"/>`.